# What is $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the strictly increasing sequence of all primes.
I'm wondering what
$$S:=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$$
is. Is the result already known? By [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) we get $S\le 2$. Can that bound be improved? Do we maybe have $S=1$?

**Remark:** I'm very thankful to all your answers.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the point of $\lim\sup$ here, but isn't $\frac 32\gt 1$ already one of the greatest values we would get?

Comment: @abiessu That's the question. Can you prove that there is no $n>1$ with $p_{n+1}/p_n \ge 3/2$?

Comment: @abiessu: No finite set of values has any influence on the [limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If abiessu could show the statement of my previous comment that would give us $S\le 3/2$, so we would have an improvement on my bound.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: that's the reference I needed, thank you

Comment: The precise meaning of   $\limsup_{n \to \infty} p_{n+1} /p_n $  is  $\lim_{n \to \infty} sup \{ p_{m+1} / p_m : m>n \}$.

Answer (score 11):

It follows from the Prime Number Theorem that 
$$
\lim_n \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=\lim_n\left( \frac{p_{n+1}}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}\cdot \frac{n\ln(n)}{p_n}\cdot \frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}\right)=1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1
$$

Now, since $ \lim_n \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=1$ then the limsup exists and is the same.

Comment: If my edit doesn't reflect what you intended, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem tells that $\lim n \ln(p_n)/p_n = 1$. But in your formular you have $n \ln(n)/p_n$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain The prime number theorem says that $$\lim_n \frac{\pi(n)}{\frac{n}{\ln(n)}}=1$$ This is equivalent to $$\lim_n \frac{p_n}{n \ln(n)}=1$$

Comment: @N.S. I don't see this. When you take $p_n$ for $n$ then we get $\pi(p_n)=n$ but I don't see how we get rid of $p_n$ in the logarithm.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain It is a very well known  simple asymptotic computation. If $\pi(n)=m$ then $p_{m} ~ n$. We know that $$m~ \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$ hence $$m \ln(n) ~ n$$ . Now, it is an easy exercise to use $m~ \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ to show that $m \ln(m) \sim m \ln(n)$,

Comment: @N.S. Are there some characters missing in your comment? I don't see how terms can be true assertions.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes, for some odd reason the $\sim$ signs didn't appear.... Here is the correct comment:  It is a very well known simple asymptotic computation. If $\pi(n)=m$ then $p_m\sim n$. We know that
$$m \sim \frac{ n}{ln(n)}$$
hence
$$mln(n) \sim n$$
. Now, it is an easy exercise to use $m \sim \frac{n}{ln(n)}$ to show that $mln(m)\sim mln(n)$.

Answer (score 9):

Yuan-You Fu-Rui Cheng, [*Explicit estimate on primes between consecutive cubes*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1268655519), showed that for $x\ge\exp(\exp(15))$ there is at least one prime between $x^3$ and $(x+1)^3$. Thus, for sufficiently large $n$ we must have

$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}<\frac{\left(p_n^{1/3}+1\right)^3}{p_n}<1+\frac7{p_n^{2/3}}\;,$$

and $S=1$.

Comment: I like this! the bound $e^{e^{15}}$ is pretty nuts... I wonder how much it could be improved!

Comment: @Eric: It answers precisely the question that was asked, and it does so in a way related in spirit to Bertrand’s postulate. You’re asking a different question.

Comment: @Eric My feeling has always been that answering a question in many different ways is encouraged universally in the mathematical community and on stackexchange. Crushing the proverbial fly with the hammer is a guilty pleasure of mathematicians of all creeds. I for one learned something new and fun reading Brian's answer, and I am sure the OP did as well.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to quote papers on prime gaps - this follows directly from the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) which states that $$\pi(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} 1=\frac{x}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log ^2 x}\right).$$ Indeed, if there existed a $c>1$ such that $p_{n+1}>cp_n$ infinitely often, then we would have $\pi(cx)=\pi(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$, however this is impossible since $$\frac{cx}{\log cx}-\frac{x}{\log x}\sim \frac{(c-1)x}{\log x}\neq O\left(\frac{cx}{\log^2 x}\right).$$

Comment: Can you give a reference  for the "big O" term in the prime number theorem?  BTW,  from $ \lim _{n \to \infty} \pi (x)/(x/ \log (x))=1 $ we easily get $ \lim_{n \to \infty} p(n)/(n \log (n))=1$ ( where $ p(n)$ is the $ n$-th prime) which implies $ \lim_{n \to \infty} p(n+1)/p(n)=1$.

Comment: Can you please explain the last line in more detail, please? In your first displayed equation do you mean $\pi(x)= \frac{x}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log ^2 x}\right)$ instead of $\pi(x)\sim \dots$?

Comment: @user254665 Nope, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot \ln(p(n))/p(n) = 1$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain. Right.....

Comment: @user254665 So what can we do about it? In the answer below I think N.S. did the same mistake but he doesn't get my point. Who is wrong there?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain. I'm posting an answer to address this.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain. Finally got around to  posting it.

Answer (score 7):

the limsup is one, see the corollary to Theorem 3 in [Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807). The information also allows you to find the maximum of the ratio, which is likely 3/2, but you can find out for sure. In any case, for $n \geq 6,$
$$ \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} < 1 + \frac{\log \log n}{\log n}, $$
so the limit is $1.$

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The value is $1$. If $c>1$ is any constant, then

$$\pi(nc) - \pi(n) \approx \frac{nc}{\log(nc)} - \frac{n}{\log(n)}$$

converges to $\infty$ when $n\to \infty$ (one can make the "$\approx$" precise). Thus for large enough $n$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $nc$, and so for all sufficiently large $n$, $p_{n+1} < cp_n$. This is enough to show that the lim sup is $1$.

Comment: More accurately, the denominators are $\ln (nc)$ and $\ln (n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $r>0$ and that  $p_{n+1}/p_n>(1+r)$ for infinitely many $n.$ We have $p_{n+1}/\log p_{n+1}\sim (n+1)$ and $p_n/\log p_n\sim n.$

Then for infinitely many $n$ we have $$1+r/2<(n+1)(\log p_{n+1})/(n\log p_n)<$$ $$<(1+1/n)(\log (1+r)+\log p_n)/\log p_n=(1+1/n)(1+(\log (1+r))/\log p_n).$$ But this last expression tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty.$